# How to return value from helper class with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to design a helper class that implements methods using AsyncTask.

```
public interface ResultCallback
{
    public String processResult();
}

public class ServerAdapter
{

    // Required processResult to call this method. Kind of lousy but I do not know
    // how to throw exception from onPostExcecute in AsyncTask.
    public String getResult() throws AirplaneModeException, NoNetworkException
    {
       // code to get return value from Dowork throw exceptions on errors
    }

    public void getLicense(ResultCallback licenseCallback)
    {
        ...// Set url, outmessage
        new Dowork(url, outMessage, licenseCallback).execute();
    }

    public void queryServer(int queryId, ArrayList<String> args, ResultCallback queryCallback)
    {
        ...// Set url, outmessage
        new Dowork(url, outmessage, queryCallback);
    }

    private class Dowork extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
    {
        ...
        private ResultCallback rc;

        public Dowork(String url, String outMessage, ResultCallback rc)
        {
            // code here
        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try
            {
                 // code here
            }
            catch (AirplaneModeException e)
            {
                return "AirplaneModeException";
            }
            catch ...
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(String result)
         {
             this.result = result;
             cb.processResult();
         }
    }
}

// Client class
public class myclass extends Activity
{
    MyServerAdapter myAdapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ...
        myAdapter = new ServerAdapter();
        myAdapter.getLicence(new MyLicenseCallback);
        myAdapter.queryServer(id, args, new MyQueryCallback);
        ...
    }

    public class MyLicenseCallback extends ResultCallback implements processResult
    {
        try
        {
            String result = myAdapter.getResult;
            ...
        }
        catch
        ... 
    }
    ...

}
```

I am new to Java and Android and have a couple of questions:

1- Would several ServerAdapter method calls cause synchronize problem? For example while   code for MyLicense callback is running, if onPostExecute calls MyQueryCallback, do I have to handle it or Java handles it?

2- How to get exception thrown in Dowork thrown in the callback instead of work around     like in the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Android guarantees you that methods in your activity and `AsyncTask.onPostExecute` runs in the same main UI thread.
2. You could save the exception in the task instance variable the same way as you do for result (return, say `null` as the result in this case). Check if exception present or not later to handle the error situation.

Comment: I do not want the implementation of the method processResult to have to check for errors. By throwing exceptions if later I decide to have the UI handles some additional error, I just change the ServerAdapter code to throw a new exception. The compiler then complains about all the codes that use the ServerAdapter so that the error can't be overlook.

Comment: Thank you for your answer number 1. For number 2, I know that I cannot throw exception from AsyncTask. That is why I have to work around with getResult and required processResult to call getResult. But the requirement is only in documentation and not having the compiler enforces it. It would be better to have the compiler enforces it or at least like C++ makes getResult pure virtual with implementation and have the derived class that implements getResult call the base class implementation (kind of super() in Java).

Comment: @Hoan Nguyen you could pass the result to `processResult` directly, so you won't have to get it by calling `getResult` on the adapter.. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I could pass the result to processResult directly, but then if later I decide to return more specific error than null string in the body of doInBackground, then I have to search all the processResult codes and rewrite the code to handle this error. I think it is better to have the compiler complains of unhandled exception and add a catch to handle this exception. This way I will not miss any of the processResult implementations.

Comment: @Hoan Nguyen ok then, I'd do the following - wrap `String result` and `Exception` into a `ServerAdapterResult` which would have method `getResult() throws AirplaneModeException, NoNetworkException`. This method inside decides whether to resurn `result` or throw an exeption based on he results of `AsyncTask` work. This way you'll have to handle all exceptions which `getResult` throws..

Comment: Ok thank you Denis Solonenko. So instead return a string I would return a class ServerAdapterResult which has a string field result, a list of exceptions and a method getResult which return result or throws exceptions from the list. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

only for turkish speakers :( http://aaarkonusurum.blogspot.com/2011/10/asynctask-classtan-donen-parametreyi.html